# Auto-hide status bar but not soft navigations keys

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to Cordova. **I could use both Cordova and Java approaches**

### I tried the manifest way:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

The status bar hid for half a second when lauinching before coming back out again. And also, why isn't my theme Black? It remained my system's default White.

### I tried the java way in my main xxx.java:

```
super.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        View rootView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
    }
});
```

But it's not actual fullscreen(flickers happen because of screen resize), it's not auto hide and both bars come back out when a tap happens.

### I tried the default fullscreen preference by Cordova

It also hides the soft navigation buttons and because reasons I don't want that to happen.

**Is there a way to auto hide the status bar but not the soft navigation bar and remain in fullscreen mode?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not the ideal way. I went in Cordova's `\src\org\apache\cordova\cordovaactivity.java` and commented out the hide navigation lines (ln 276 in my case):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void toggleFullscreen(Window window) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final int uiOptions =
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
              /*| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION*/
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
              /*| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION*/
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
              /*| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY*/;

        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    } else {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```